Form loading blank c#
This is the first time I am facing this issue. I want to call a form from my main form using Show() method. The form loads but it is blank. In my form2, I have 2 labels and one picturebox.
My code :
Home.cs
btnClick()
{
PleaseWait pleasewait = new PleaseWait();
pleasewait.Show();

//do something

pleasewait.close();

}

Pleasewait.cs
public PleaseWait
{
 InitializeComponent();
}


I debugged InitializeComponent() step by step but nothing threw exception.
but when I form loaded, it was blank.
My issue is same as this issue -
Windows form not showing control C#
My form is loading exactly like this when I run it but the actual designer has controls.
I tried the solution mentioned and did public PleaseWait(): this() but it gives me error saying Constructor cannot call itself.

you probably need public PleaseWait() : base() { InitializeComponent; }, not this().

@MakePeaceGreatAgain   Tried this but same issue

Please provide a [mcve] rather than pseudo-code. The code you've provided wouldn't compile at all.

Consider making //do something an async Task (or putting it in a different thread with a BackgroundWorker if you prefer the old-school approach).  Windows forms applications are event driven, and you must not do heavy lifting or a perform long-running computation in a click handler because it will make the UI unresponsive.  Application.DoEvents is hacky.  Tasks are the way.

@Wyck thank you I will use the async task. Thanks for the guidance.

Adding
Application.DoEvents(); // Allows the form to render before continuing

solved the issue.

That's almost always a bad idea. But as you've only provided pseudo-code rather than a [mcve], we can't easily help you work out a better approach.

@JonSkeet my apologies. I will not be able to share the code that's why I posted a sample. But thanks for the guidance I will use the async task. Thank you.

You never need to post your actual business-sensitive code - but I don't see what's stopping you from posting a [mcve] instead of pseudo-code that doesn't compile anyway, and doesn't demonstrate the problem.
